# F4 visa processing - receipt but no approval

Tags: visa

When I search for my case number for an F4 visa application in USCIS page, I see the following message:

On September 25, 2017, we received your Form I-130, Petition for Alien Relative, Receipt Number xxxx and sent you the receipt notice that describes how we will process your case.

The stipulated processing time for my country for F4 visas is around 20 years. But I was wondering if I should expect any further communication in the interim after the receipt notice?